# Create .app file on Mac from runnable jar

Tags: macos, osx-lion, .app

- I Have Created a sample.app file which is running on Mac , this .app file is created with the
    references from [URL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Unl8dgqFv6o)

  ```
          - This .app file contains 
                  ----> Content (Folder)
                              ----> info.plist
                              ----> MacOS(subfolder)
                                          ---->ButtonDemo.jar (runnable jar)
                                          ---->launch (unix executable script)
                              ----> Resources(subfolder)
                                          ----->application.icns(icon images)

         -  Same above procedure I followed for my runnable (iwb.jar) file which are placed accordingly with its dependencies ,

         - This iwb.app file contains 
                  ----> Content (Folder)
                              ----> info.plist
                              ----> MacOS(subfolder)
                                          ---->iwb.jar (runnable jar)
                                          ---->DerbyDatabase (dependent database)
                                          ---->jre (dependant jre)
                                          ---->props (property configuration)
                                          ---->server (jetty server)
                                          ---->launch (unix executable script)
                              ----> Resources(subfolder)
                                          ----->application.icns(icon images)
  ```

  This following iwb.jar (runnable jar). IF once executed it starts the jetty server application and opens the browser with the JettyServer Home Page.

but I'm getting this following Exception: `" LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error - 10810 " on Mac OS X version 10.8.4`